# Fill NaN value in columns with other columns with new columns creation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to fill the `NaN` value in selected columns with the values from other selected columns and create a range of new columns after the filling. I can do this one by one by using `fillna()` with the other column names and create the column but I wonder how I can do this at scale, or at least some ways to reduce the repeating.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inp = [
    {'a1hk':10, 'a2hk':100, 'b1uk':50, 'b2uk':80, 'd1dk':90, 'c1jk':np.nan, 'c1mk':np.nan, 'c2pk':np.nan, 'c2wk':np.nan}, 
    {'a1hk':11,'a2hk':50, 'b1uk':50, 'b2uk':80, 'd1dk':90, 'c1jk':np.nan, 'c1mk':np.nan, 'c2pk':np.nan, 'c2wk':np.nan}, 
    {'a1hk':11,'a2hk':50, 'b1uk':50, 'b2uk':80, 'd1dk':90, 'c1jk':20, 'c1mk':50, 'c2pk':60, 'c2wk':80}, 
    {'a1hk':np.nan,'a2hk':np.nan, 'b1uk':np.nan, 'b2uk':np.nan, 'd1dk':np.nan, 'c1jk':50, 'c1mk':100, 'c2pk':60, 'c2wk':70}, 
    {'a1hk':np.nan,'a2hk':np.nan, 'b1uk':np.nan, 'b2uk':np.nan, 'd1dk':np.nan, 'c1jk':50, 'c1mk':100, 'c2pk':60, 'c2wk':80}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df

   a1hk   a2hk  b1uk  b2uk  d1dk  c1jk  c1mk  c2pk  c2wk
0  10.0  100.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0  20.0  50.0  60.0  80.0
3   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0   NaN  60.0  70.0
4   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0   NaN  60.0  80.0


The columns needs to get filled: a1hk, a2hk, b1uk, b2uk, d1dk
The columns where we get the value: c1jk, c1mk, c2pk, c2wk

df['a1hk_jk'] = df['a1hk'].fillna(df['c1jk'])
df['a2hk_mk'] = df['a1hk'].fillna(df['c1mk'])
df['a1hk_pk'] = df['a1hk'].fillna(df['c2pk'])
df['a1hk_wk'] = df['a1hk'].fillna(df['c2wk'])
df['a2hk_jk'] = df['a2hk'].fillna(df['c1jk'])
....
....
....
df['d1dk_jk'] = df['d1dk'].fillna(df['c1jk'])
df['d1dk_mk'] = df['d1dk'].fillna(df['c1mk'])
df['d1dk_pk'] = df['d1dk'].fillna(df['c2pk'])
df['d1dk_wk'] = df['d1dk'].fillna(df['c2wk'])

# Expected output (minimal)
   a1hk   a2hk  b1uk  b2uk  d1dk  c1jk   c1mk  c2pk  c2wk  a1hk_jk  a2hk_mk  a1hk_pk  a1hk_wk  d1dk_jk  d1dk_mk  d1dk_pk  d1dk_wk
0  10.0  100.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN     10.0     10.0     10.0     10.0     90.0     90.0     90.0     90.0 
1  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN     11.0     11.0     11.0     11.0     90.0     90.0     90.0     90.0 
2  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0  20.0   50.0  60.0  80.0     11.0     11.0     11.0     11.0     90.0     90.0     90.0     90.0 
3   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0  60.0  70.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     70.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     70.0 
4   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0  60.0  80.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     80.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     80.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list from source and destination columns and call function in `for loop`, for new columns names is used `f-string`s with last 2 letters of destination values:

```
source = 'a1hk, a2hk, b1uk, b2uk, d1dk'.split(', ')
dest = 'c1jk, c1mk, c2pk, c2wk'.split(', ')

for x, y in zip(source, dest):
    df[f'{x}_{y[-2:]}'] = df[x].fillna(df[y])
print (df)
   a1hk   a2hk  b1uk  b2uk  d1dk  c1jk   c1mk  c2pk  c2wk  a1hk_jk  a2hk_mk  \
0  10.0  100.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN     10.0    100.0   
1  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN     11.0     50.0   
2  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0  20.0   50.0  60.0  80.0     11.0     50.0   
3   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0  60.0  70.0     50.0    100.0   
4   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0  60.0  80.0     50.0    100.0   

   b1uk_pk  b2uk_wk  
0     50.0     80.0  
1     50.0     80.0  
2     50.0     80.0  
3     60.0     70.0  
4     60.0     80.0
```

EDIT: For combinations all values in lists use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from  itertools import product
source = 'a1hk, a2hk, b1uk, b2uk, d1dk'.split(', ')
dest = 'c1jk, c1mk, c2pk, c2wk'.split(', ')

for x, y in product(source, dest):
    df[f'{x}_{y[-2:]}'] = df[x].fillna(df[y])
print (df)
   a1hk   a2hk  b1uk  b2uk  d1dk  c1jk   c1mk  c2pk  c2wk  a1hk_jk  a1hk_mk  \
0  10.0  100.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN     10.0     10.0   
1  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN     11.0     11.0   
2  11.0   50.0  50.0  80.0  90.0  20.0   50.0  60.0  80.0     11.0     11.0   
3   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0  60.0  70.0     50.0    100.0   
4   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0  60.0  80.0     50.0    100.0   

   a1hk_pk  a1hk_wk  a2hk_jk  a2hk_mk  a2hk_pk  a2hk_wk  b1uk_jk  b1uk_mk  \
0     10.0     10.0    100.0    100.0    100.0    100.0     50.0     50.0   
1     11.0     11.0     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0   
2     11.0     11.0     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0   
3     60.0     70.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     70.0     50.0    100.0   
4     60.0     80.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     80.0     50.0    100.0   

   b1uk_pk  b1uk_wk  b2uk_jk  b2uk_mk  b2uk_pk  b2uk_wk  d1dk_jk  d1dk_mk  \
0     50.0     50.0     80.0     80.0     80.0     80.0     90.0     90.0   
1     50.0     50.0     80.0     80.0     80.0     80.0     90.0     90.0   
2     50.0     50.0     80.0     80.0     80.0     80.0     90.0     90.0   
3     60.0     70.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     70.0     50.0    100.0   
4     60.0     80.0     50.0    100.0     60.0     80.0     50.0    100.0   

   d1dk_pk  d1dk_wk  
0     90.0     90.0  
1     90.0     90.0  
2     90.0     90.0  
3     60.0     70.0  
4     60.0     80.0
```

Comment: Wow, this is succinct and nicely done! One question: Is there a way to get the source and dest variables in a more programmatic style given I have a longer list of column names to put down.

Comment: @codedancer - Sorry, not see comment. So it depends how get this columns? Is possible logic pairs are first 5 columnsnames for source and then next 5 columnsnames for destination? Or logic is more complicated?

Comment: I was thinking to use `[x for x in df.columns.values.tolist() if 'hk' in x]` to pick up the partial string and use `tuple()` to convert the list for the source and dest variable. It seems that I am still one step away to achieve the goal. Any suggestion?

Comment: @codedancer - yes, but first `hk` endstring match `jk`, secon `hk` match `mk`. So this is problem how define pairs. I cannot see some logic here, so lists `a,b` are created. But maybe some logic is here.

Comment: Sorry I found a problem with the solution. It doesn't give me the result where every item of source get filled by every item of dest. In this case, `a1hk` would get filled 4 times by 'c1jk, c1mk, c2pk, c2wk' with 4 newly created columns related to `a1hk` and then the next one `a2hk` and next one. You could have a look at my original expected result.

Comment: @codedancer - answer was edited.